# How to remove spacing in a string without using "\\s" in JAVA?

Tags: java, removing-whitespace

I know how to remove spacing with `.replaceAll("\\s+","");`. But what i need is something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<string.length();i++) {
   if(ch==32) {
     //remove the character;
   }
}
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: I have been thinking over this question for a while now, and this is the farthest i could come.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String str = "a b c d e";
String newStr = "";
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch != 32)
        newStr += ch;
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

It will prints `abcde`.

Comment: `String += String` (or `String += char`) in a loop is a bad idea (bad performance). If you're gonna write the code for them, at least teach it the right way to do it, i.e. using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: As @Andreas said, String concatenation is bad habit because it generates a new string every time. So `StringBuilder` or `List<String>` (with `String.join`) is good to use. But I think a short code is more readable.

Comment: Also note that this handles only the space character, while `\\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` - it handles whitespace, newlines etc.